# NavigationPage rendere for android. Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I am trying to access the actionbar from a custom renderer(i know i can use the toolbar.xml but it's not fitting my situation). **Here is my code**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(NoviNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace NoviMobileTest.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class NoviNavigationPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
                base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
                var actionBar = ((Activity)Context).ActionBar;
                actionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.YourImageInDrawable));
        }
    }
}
```

variable `actionbar` is always null. I also tried extending NavigationRenderer but i get class cast exception.  I've seen many people having the same issue but it's amazing that there are no examples out there to see. How am i suppose to get instance of the toolbar?

NOTE: 
my MainActivity extends `FormsAppCompatActivity`

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the line you declare actionBar is the 'Context' you use Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context?

Comment: no it's Android.Content.Context. I also tried Forms but still returns null

Comment: That's your issue. That context isn't an actual activity in your app, so it has no action bar. You need to use the current activity of your app like Wilson Vargas does in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing [CurrentActivity Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity/) in your Android project and then like this:

```
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
...
private static Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar GetToolbar() => (CrossCurrentActivity.Current?.Activity as MainActivity)?.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
```

Finally:

```
protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var actionBar = GetToolbar();
            actionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.YourImageInDrawable));
    }
```

For more information about this see: [IconNavigationPageRenderer.cs](https://github.com/wilsonvargas/CustomIconNavigationPage/blob/master/src/CustomIcon/CustomIcon.Android/IconNavigationPageRenderer.cs#L24)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunatelly it still returns null

Comment: Your suggestion was right and in fact it returns the right context. The problem was that i was rendering a `NavigationPage` while it had no action bar when it was called.

Comment: Include if (actionBar != null) { actionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable... }